# Re-order Matrix Column Python

Tags: python, matrix, rgb, multiple-columns

I have a LUT (look up table).  It defines how to modify RGB values.  I have a matrix 3 x 4912,  It represents RGB values but in the incorrect order.  Rather than RGB the columns represent BGR.  I would like to re-arrange so the BGR becomes RGB.

I am on an OS X machine.  I have Python installed.  I was hoping there is a Python solution, however, I am open to others.

Here is a sample of the matrix.

```
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
0.0626 0.0000 0.0000
0.1529 0.0000 0.0000
0.2000 0.0000 0.0000
0.2549 0.0000 0.0000
0.3176 0.0000 0.0000
```

Comment: A numpy matrix? What have you tried so far? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: If you're using numpy, I'd recommend looking at the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Comment: @Magitrek, thank you for the link!  I am not a programmer, I frankly did not know where to even begin.  At least now I have a direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

reverse the lists

```
for i in table:
    i.reverse()
```